# write c# code in JavaScript function in Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

my question is very short want to this :

```
$(document).on('click', '.ee', function(){
                $('.b').val("@Model.Result.GoingDate.AddDays(-1).ToString()");
                @{Model.Result.GoingDate = Model.Result.GoingDate.AddDays(-1); }
            });
```

but it's not working 
is there any other way to that?

I know I can use javascript date 
but don't know how

Comment: Please define "_it's not working_". What you want your code to do, and what it does instead? Is any error message occurring? If yes, in the server code or in JS code? And what is the error message?

Comment: that razor syntax only works when the view is initialized, I mean its work on single time  but I want that to work every time that button is clicked

Comment: Yes, because the values in the script are created at the server before the page is loaded. The values are static at the client-side, please see the source code to see what actually has been rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant do that with razor instead 
use this method I kind of know what you need

you want to go to next day and update your text in HTML

```
$(document).on('click', '.ee', function () {
                    var currentDate  = $('.txt-date').val();
                    var gdate = new Date(currentDate); 
                    gdate.setDate(gdate.getDate() + 1);
                    $('.b').val(goingDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10));
                });
```